# How to set SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, limit

I've written a small C# application that runs on Linux via Mono and uses SQLite to store log files read from disk in a database.

The bottleneck I'm facing is that because the log files can have 222000+ entries each (with sometimes 1000's of log files at a time), the write actions on my database are taking up the most amount of time that the program is running.

Is there any way to increase the SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT limit from SQLite? As the max amount of entries that I can write to the database at once is 500 (which I am already using).

I know there is a C interface (`sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT,size)`), but I'd much rather set that via C# instead of going into C to do it.

Comment: How are you using the SQLite database currently from C#? What library or driver?

Comment: Mono.Data.Sqlite, which comes with a Mono installation

Comment: Why do you think that statements with more records in them would make your program *effectively* faster?

Comment: I don't know. I want to see if it in fact does make a difference if I write larger chunks at once to the database. My reason being that I have so many log entries, and 500 is only a small part of that. So now I have a lot of write actions on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enhance the performance of writing to the database I've switched from compound select statements to prepared statements. This improved execution speed substantially.

If before a log file, 100Mb in size, took 1min 30sec to be written to the db, now it only took 30sec for the file to be processed. Though this is not guaranteed for someone else, it suffices in my situation.

I've used [this](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.nl/2007/02/sqlite-adonet-prepared-statements.html) link in order to do this. Though old, this still applies today.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's merely a C routine, you can call it from C# via pInvoke:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3.dll")]
static extern int sqlite3_limit(IntPtr dbHandle, int id, int newVal);
```

You then need to get your dbHandle which, in Mono.Data.Sqlite, I believe is in:

SqliteConnection._sql.handle.

To get to this, you'll need reflection.

I haven't tested this (I don't have Mono or sqlite), but I believe this will do it:

```
private void SetLimit(SqliteConnection conn, int newLimit)
{
   object sqlVar = conn.GetType().GetProperty("_sql", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(conn);
   IntPtr dbHandle = (IntPtr) sqlVar.GetType().GetProperty("handle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(sqlVar);
   sqlite3_limit(dbHandle, 4, newLimit);
}
```

4 is the hardcoded value of the SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT constant.

**Update**

The connection will need to be open when you call this, I believe and it will only last the duration of the connection.

Comment: GetValue requires more than just and object as a parameter. It also requires BindingFlags, a Binder, an object[] with indexes and a CultureInfo.

Comment: Scrap that, it will also suffice to only use null as an extra parameter. This results in GetValue(obj, null).

Comment: Is there somewhere where I can find the sqlite3.dll? All I can find are either infected files or the normal sqlite3.exe from the sqlite site.

Comment: Dumb mistake on my end. I found the dll. But I can't reference it in VS2010.

Comment: @ThaMe90 You don't need to reference it, you simply need to have it in the same directory as your app (either that, or specify the path in the DllImport attribute. It's not a managed DLL, so you can't reference it.

Comment: @ThaMe90 As for the GetValue, I use .NET 4.5, which has a GetValue() that takes only a single parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx. But yes, you can pass null as the other parameter for the 2 parameter version.

Comment: Tried as I have, but I could not get DllImport to work. I've actually found a different solution to my performance problem.